# Define ng-model for this JSON input array - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, model, controller

**Goal:** 
I have to PUT this data with this structure:

```
"open_hours": [ // (See that open_hours is an array).
      {
        "weekday": "mon",
        "opens_at": "09:00",
        "closes_at": "22:00"
      },
      {
        "weekday": "tue",
        "opens_at": "09:00",
        "closes_at": "22:00"
      }
  ]
```

into this **controller.js:**

```
$scope.days = ["sun","mon","tue","wed","thu","fri","sat"];

$scope.restaurant = {};
$scope.restaurant.open_hours = [];
```

In order to be viewed in this **template** (`angular-bootstrap-ui timePicker` directive):

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-condensed">
          <tbody ng-repeat="day in days">
            <tr>
              <td>
                <input type="hidden" ng-model="restaurant.open_hours[day].weekday" ng-value="day"/>
                {{day}}
              </td>
              <td>
                Opens at <uib-timepicker ng-model="restaurant.open_hours[day].opens_at" show-meridian="false" show-spinners="false" minute-step="15"></uib-timepicker>
              </td>
              <td>
                Closes at <uib-timepicker ng-model="restaurant.open_hours[day].closes_at" show-meridian="false" show-spinners="false" minute-step="15"></uib-timepicker>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
```

How to do it? In all my attempts I did not succeed.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to have the a date object used to populate the timepicker.

```
var time = new Date();
  time.setHours(9);
  time.setMinutes(0);
  var closeTime = new Date();
  closeTime.setHours(22);
  closeTime.setMinutes(0);
  $scope.restaurant = {
    "open_hours": [
  {
    "weekday": "mon",
    "opens_at": time,
    "closes_at": closeTime
  },
  {
    "weekday": "tue",
    "opens_at": time,
    "closes_at": closeTime
  }
]};
```

here is a [codepen](http://codepen.io/mkl/pen/AXRLLj) that shows a working example.

Comment: We are almost there, now when I populate other day with some time, the day is added to the array but without thw weekday value, eg.:
    {
      "opens_at": "2016-06-30T14:50:16.334Z",
      "closes_at": "2016-06-30T15:50:16.336Z"
    }

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but maybe you need a hidden input for the weekday property.